# Image border gets toggled on & off everytime it is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick, border

I am trying to do include 3 images on my page. These images must have the following behavior done: When an unbordered image is clicked, it gets a border on it. When a bordered imaged is clicked, the border gets removed. In other words the border gets toggled on & off every time it is clicked, for that image.

I can get the border on when clicked, but I can not figure out how to remove it again.

This is what I have for JS so far:

```
ims = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for( i=0 ; i<ims.length ; i++ ){

  ims[i].onclick=function(){

    this.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    this.style.borderColor = "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, consider selecting a correct answer if you consider one of them was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the style:

```
    ims[i].onclick=function() {

        if (this.style.borderStyle == "solid") {
            this.style.borderStyle = "none";
        } else {
            this.style.borderStyle = "solid";
            this.style.borderColor = "red";
        }

    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkQEx/)

Comment: Do I remove the "for loop"?

Comment: nope, you do not! +1 btw, even if I would have preferred classes myself!

Comment: Thank you. I just tested your code and it adds a border to the image if I click on it once, but when I click on the image again, the border doesn't go away. Any advise?

Comment: @user2147761 [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkQEx/). I think the problem was I accidentally made a typo (`==` -> `=`), sorry :)

Comment: Good answer, but I would go with classes, you could enhance the styles behavior in the futures with much ease.

Comment: @Chango Yes, but I was trying to keep it as simple and as similar as possible with the OP's code. I guess I will post some sample code with classes once I wake up next morning (going to sleep now).

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will try with classes for next time. Still little new to this:)

Comment: Thank You!! IT works perfect!!
PS. you meant go with classes instead of Tag?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a solution based on Doorknob, but with classes, as I recommended on the comment:

```
var ims = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for( var i=0 ; i<ims.length ; i++ ){
  ims[i].onclick=function() {
    if (this.className == "clicked") {
      this.className = "";
    } else {
      this.className = "clicked";
    }
  };
}
```

And the css classes:

```
img {
  padding: 5px;
}
img.clicked {
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Here you can see the benefits of using classes.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwg74/).

For further investigation I would recommend to check how to do it if the `img` tag has multiple classes ;). Ask again if you have any doubts.